# Getting exception while connecting a server through SSH

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, ssh, solaris

I am trying to connect to an external server from my Solaris server using SSH in my Java application. Some how we are getting exception while authenticating the user but after 60min. How can we decrease the timing to get the exception to 5min or so.

*There was a problem while connecting to IP:PORT
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to IP:PORT*

The time difference between time2 and time3 are around 60min. I want to decrease this time.

Please find below the code snippet that we are using.

```
try
{
    timeout = 1;
    if (connection == null)
    {
        //time1
        connection = new ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection(getIpAddress(), Integer.parseInt(getPort()));
        if (connection == null)
        {
            System.out.println("connection is null");
        }
        else
        {
            //time2
            connection.connect(null, timeout, 0);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception t)
{
    //time3
    System.out.println(t.getLocalizedMessage());
    System.out.println(t.toString());
}
```

Edit1: After checking SSH related configuration files I found KeyRegenerationInterval having a value of 3600s. Is this useful to resolve this issue. What might be the outcome if I decrease its value to some 30min or 5min.

Comment: Did you try to connect with ssh client to this particular IP:port?

Comment: @Romeo Nivon yes we are able to connect to that IP:PORT

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize your problem, please correct me if something wrong.

1. You can not connect to SSH server.
2. An exception raised after 60 mins.

According to below Throws section of method [connect(ServerHostKeyVerifier, int, int)](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection.html#connect(ch.ethz.ssh2.ServerHostKeyVerifier,%20int,%20int)), I guess you might be facing issue due to a buggy proxy which doesn't return proper HTTP response. Using direct internet connection to see whether the issue is gone.

> **Throws:**
>
> java.io.IOException - If any problem occurs, e.g., the server's host key is not accepted by the verifier or there is problem during
>   the initial crypto setup (e.g., the signature sent by the server is
>   wrong).
>
> In case of a timeout (either connectTimeout or kexTimeout) a SocketTimeoutException is thrown.
>
> An exception may also be thrown if the connection was already successfully connected (no matter if the connection broke in the mean
>   time) and you invoke connect() again without having called [close()](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection.html#close())
>   first.
>
> If a HTTP proxy is being used and the proxy refuses the connection, then a [HTTPProxyException](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/HTTPProxyException.html) may be thrown, which contains
>   the details returned by the proxy. If the proxy is buggy and does not
>   return a proper HTTP response, then a normal IOException is thrown
>   instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. My requirement here is it get the exception little earlier than to wait for 60min. Is there a way to do that. This issue I am facing in production server not in test servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "kexTimeout" (Timeout for complete connection establishment (non-negative, in milliseconds). Zero means no timeout.) to non-zero

```
connection.connect(null, timeout, timeout);
```

Also, in your catch print the full stacktrace to verify where the timeout occurs

```
catch (Exception t) {
    //time3
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Even if I do that exception will come after 60min right as per the below description for kexTimeout from  http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection.html#connect()

kexTimeout - Timeout for complete connection establishment (non-negative, in milliseconds). Zero means no timeout. The timeout counts from the moment you invoke the connect() method and is cancelled as soon as the first key-exchange round has finished. It is possible that the timeout event will be fired during the invocation of the verifier callback, but it will only have an effect after the verifier returns

Comment: As per the above meaning kexTimeout will be checked after invocation of verifier callback. Can you explain me what is that and how we can reduce the time to invoke this verification.

Comment: @rmkyjv, could you please add the stacktrace from the timeout to your description.

Comment: Sorry @Simon, as of now we don't have the exact stack trace with us. We are not able to replicate this in test. And this issue is rarely popping up in production server only.